# Get Keras input tensor from model

Tags: keras

I'm working through the Keras example for a sequence to sequence model.

https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/lstm_seq2seq.py

In this example, they build a model from an input tensor.

```
encoder_inputs = Input(shape=(None, num_encoder_tokens))
model = Model([encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs], decoder_outputs)
print(encoder_inputs)
```

output:

```
Tensor("input_1:0", shape=(?, ?, 71), dtype=float32)
```

Once a model is built, is there a way to retrieve the input tensor from the model?  Something along the lines of

```
encoder_inputs = model.layers[0].??????
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is simply `model.input` or `model.inputs`